# How create widget and display in my form?

Tags: forms, widget, odoo

How do I create my first widget?
And how to display it on my form view?
If someone can give me a very detailed example, that would be great.
A simple widget displaying a text/button in my form.
Just so I understand how it works.
I've tested several things but nothing works.
Please help me !!!!!

Comment: Need information about your odoo version.

Comment: my version is odoo 14